# Parameter pack ignored by deduction

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, variadic-templates

Why can't my `gcc-5.4.0` not deduce parameter packs if they do not appear in the end of the argument list of a function? While the call to `works` is deduced in a correct way way to `works<int,int,int>`, the call to `fails` is not deduced but instead only an empty parameter pack is assumed. Leading to an error message about too many provided arguments for the function.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename...args_t>
void works (int first, args_t...args) {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}

template <typename...args_t, typename last_t, typename=void>
void fails (args_t...args, last_t last) {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}

int main () {
    works (0, 1, 2, 3);
    fails (0, 1, 2, 3);
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:** as the answers explained, it is not allowed to have typenames after the parameter packs. But according to [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack), it should be valid to have other template parameters after it, if they may be deduced. Apparently the given example does not compile with my `gcc`. Instead it stays with the same error about too many given arguments.

```
#include <iostream>
template <typename...args_t, typename U, typename=void>
static int valid (args_t...args, U u) {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    return u;
}

int main () {
    return valid(0, 0.0, -1, 3u);
}
```

Comment: Are you asking _if_ those are the rules or _why_ those are the rules?

Comment: as `gcc` does not compile it, I expect it to be the rules. As I could not find anything about why this is so, i would be glad to hear what the reason for it. Of course I would also like to see a way to circumvent it.. (;

Comment: @Jonas It fails with other compilers just in the same way.

Comment: Cppreference fixed (it got the order of the function arguments wrong)

Answer (score 1):

> Why can't my `gcc-5.4.0` not deduce parameter packs if they do not appear in the end of the argument list of a function?

Because you cannot specify any types beyond the variadic parameter pack like that

```
 void fails (args_...args, int last)
                      // ^^^^^^^^^^
```

It's merely the same problem as with default parameter values, or plain ellipsis (`...`) that those need to be open towards the end of the parameter list (or say they're required to be the last element):

```
 void fails(int x = 0, int last);
 void fails(int x, ..., int last);
```